# Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly Error launching application

Tags: android, flutter

**Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly Error launching application on vivo 1811**

When i click on run button in android studio it install the `APK` on my mobile but than the app did not proceed and it's halt and on android studio it gives me above error I also run `flutter clean` command in my project but it also did not work. I also uninstall app than tried again but it also did not have any effect.after running flutter doctor every thing is running fine. I restart my mobile connect and disconnect USB debug mode give USB file transfer permission but all in vain.

This is the output of `flutter doctor --verbose`

`flutter doctor -v`

```sh
`PS C:\Users\User> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1440], locale en-PK)
    • Flutter version 2.0.4 at C:\flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision b1395592de (3 days ago), 2021-04-01 14:25:01 -0700
    • Engine revision 2dce47073a
    • Dart version 2.12.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.55.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.114
    • Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 89.0.774.45

• No issues found!
```

Output Running from terminal
`flutter create app`
`cd app`
`flutter run -v`

This is my `flutter run -v` output from terminal

```sh
PS C:\Users\User\desktop\app\app> flutter run -v                                                                                                                        [ +119 ms] executing: [C:\flutter\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[ +103 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +2 ms] b1395592de68cc8ac4522094ae59956dd21a91db
[   +1 ms] executing: [C:\flutter\flutter/] git tag --points-at b1395592de68cc8ac4522094ae59956dd21a91db
[  +73 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at b1395592de68cc8ac4522094ae59956dd21a91db
[   +1 ms] 2.0.4
[  +62 ms] executing: [C:\flutter\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +60 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +1 ms] origin/stable
[   +4 ms] executing: [C:\flutter\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +52 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +2 ms] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[ +106 ms] executing: [C:\flutter\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +65 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +2 ms] stable
[ +141 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +5 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +90 ms] executing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[  +89 ms] List of devices attached
           bea90680               device product:1811 model:vivo_1811 device:1811 transport_id:6
[  +25 ms] C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s bea90680 shell getprop
[ +132 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +10 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +6 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +173 ms] Skipping pub get: version match.
[ +188 ms] Generating C:\Users\User\Desktop\app\app\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[  +81 ms] ro.hardware = qcom
[  +59 ms] Initializing file store
[  +16 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[  +14 ms] complete
[  +13 ms] Launching lib\main.dart on vivo 1811 in debug mode...
[   +8 ms] C:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --disable-dart-dev C:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\windows-x64\frontend_server.dart.snapshot
--sdk-root C:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --incremental --target=flutter --debugger-module-names
--experimental-emit-debug-metadata --output-dill C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tools.9a15992a\flutter_tool.18b78d4e\app.dill --packages
C:\Users\User\Desktop\app\app\.dart_tool\package_config.json -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation
--filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root --initialize-from-dill build\cache.dill.track.dill
[  +32 ms] executing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s bea90680 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +22 ms] <- compile package:app/main.dart
[ +295 ms] --------- beginning of main
                    04-06 19:59:18.256 E/qti_sensors_hal(  600): processReportInd: lux: 104.000000, photopic: 833.000000, ir: 0.000000
[  +21 ms] executing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe version
[ +121 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
                    Version 31.0.1-7187441
                    Installed as C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
[   +8 ms] executing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
[  +69 ms] Building APK
[  +51 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[  +12 ms] Using gradle from C:\Users\User\Desktop\app\app\android\gradlew.bat.
[   +3 ms] C:\Users\User\Desktop\app\app\android\gradlew.bat mode: 33279 rwxrwxrwx.
[  +30 ms] executing: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[ +651 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[   +2 ms] openjdk version "1.8.0_242-release"
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b01, mixed mode)
[   +6 ms] executing: [C:\Users\User\Desktop\app\app\android/] C:\Users\User\Desktop\app\app\android\gradlew.bat -Pverbose=true -Ptarget-platform=android-arm64
-Ptarget=C:\Users\User\Desktop\app\app\lib\main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug
[+5990 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
[+36544 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug
[   +4 ms] [ +109 ms] executing: [C:\flutter\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +93 ms] [ +118 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +7 ms] [        ] b1395592de68cc8ac4522094ae59956dd21a91db
[   +1 ms] [   +1 ms] executing: [C:\flutter\flutter/] git tag --points-at b1395592de68cc8ac4522094ae59956dd21a91db
[  +90 ms] [  +98 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at b1395592de68cc8ac4522094ae59956dd21a91db
[   +3 ms] [        ] 2.0.4
[  +96 ms] [  +59 ms] executing: [C:\flutter\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +3 ms] [  +72 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +3 ms] [        ] origin/stable
[   +1 ms] [        ] executing: [C:\flutter\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +91 ms] [  +55 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +2 ms] [        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +96 ms] [ +112 ms] executing: [C:\flutter\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +99 ms] [  +69 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +2 ms] [        ] stable
[  +97 ms] [  +77 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] [  +14 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +73 ms] [  +85 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MaterialFonts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'GradleWrapper' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +6 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FontSubsetArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'PubDependencies' is not required, skipping update.
[  +44 ms] [  +93 ms] Initializing file store
[   +2 ms] [  +31 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[   +1 ms] [  +20 ms] kernel_snapshot: Starting due to {}
[   +4 ms] [  +28 ms] C:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --disable-dart-dev
C:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\windows-x64\frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
C:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --target=flutter --no-print-incremental-dependencies -Ddart.vm.profile=false
-Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --no-link-platform --packages C:\Users\User\Desktop\app\app\.dart_tool\package_config.json
--output-dill C:\Users\User\Desktop\app\app\.dart_tool\flutter_build\f6ecaec9bb2953261ad1e0d017893acb\app.dill --depfile
C:\Users\User\Desktop\app\app\.dart_tool\flutter_build\f6ecaec9bb2953261ad1e0d017893acb\kernel_snapshot.d package:app/main.dart
[+13391 ms] [+13329 ms] kernel_snapshot: Complete
[ +799 ms] [ +839 ms] debug_android_application: Starting due to {}
[+1101 ms] [+1105 ms] debug_android_application: Complete
[ +999 ms] [+1020 ms] Persisting file store
[   +2 ms] [  +19 ms] Done persisting file store
[  +98 ms] [  +23 ms] build succeeded.
[   +2 ms] [  +30 ms] "flutter assemble" took 16,671ms.
[   +5 ms] [   +8 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 1ms
[   +4 ms] [   +3 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[   +2 ms] [        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +3 ms] [        ] exiting with code 0
[ +581 ms] > Task :app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug
[   +2 ms] > Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[   +4 ms] > Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[  +91 ms] > Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
[ +700 ms] > Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata
[   +2 ms] > Task :app:cleanMergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[ +149 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
[  +59 ms] > Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
[  +82 ms] > Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[   +5 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
[ +598 ms] > Task :app:copyFlutterAssetsDebug
[   +2 ms] > Task :app:generateDebugResValues
[   +4 ms] > Task :app:generateDebugResources
[+3178 ms] > Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
[  +63 ms] > Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug
[ +455 ms] > Task :app:processDebugMainManifest
[  +96 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugResources
[ +707 ms] > Task :app:processDebugManifest
[  +91 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
[   +3 ms] > Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
[ +110 ms] > Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
[+1585 ms] > Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
[ +600 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
[ +506 ms] > Task :app:compressDebugAssets
[ +211 ms] > Task :app:validateSigningDebug
[   +5 ms] > Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage
[+1077 ms] > Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies
[+1998 ms] > Task :app:processDebugResources
[+8401 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs
[+8300 ms] > Task :app:compileDebugKotlin
[+4020 ms] > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
[  +65 ms] > Task :app:compileDebugSources
[+1642 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource
[ +969 ms] > Task :app:dexBuilderDebug
[+2193 ms] > Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols
[   +6 ms] Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libflutter.so.
[+1911 ms] > Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug
[+1887 ms] > Task :app:mergeDexDebug
[+8401 ms] > Task :app:packageDebug
[+1098 ms] > Task :app:assembleDebug
[+1500 ms] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
[   +2 ms] Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[   +5 ms] See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[   +1 ms] BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 52s
[   +1 ms] 32 actionable tasks: 31 executed, 1 up-to-date
[+1455 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 115.4s)
[+1191 ms] calculateSha: LocalDirectory: 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\app\app\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk'/app.apk
[  +53 ms] calculateSha: reading file took 50us
[+1232 ms] calculateSha: computing sha took 1230us
[  +14 ms] √ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
[ +547 ms] executing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.3\aapt dump xmltree C:\Users\User\Desktop\app\app\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk
AndroidManifest.xml
[+3362 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.3\aapt dump xmltree
C:\Users\User\Desktop\app\app\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[   +3 ms] N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
             E: manifest (line=2)
               A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
               A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x1e
               A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="11" (Raw: "11")
               A: package="com.example.app" (Raw: "com.example.app")
               A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x1e
               A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0xb
               E: uses-sdk (line=7)
                 A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x10
                 A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x1e
               E: uses-permission (line=14)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw: "android.permission.INTERNET")
               E: application (line=16)
                 A: android:label(0x01010001)="app" (Raw: "app")
                 A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
                 A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" (Raw: "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
                 E: activity (line=21)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0a0000
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.example.app.MainActivity" (Raw: "com.example.app.MainActivity")
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x40003fb4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: meta-data (line=35)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" (Raw: "io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f0a0001
                   E: meta-data (line=45)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" (Raw: "io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f040000
                   E: intent-filter (line=49)
                     E: action (line=50)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
                     E: category (line=52)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                 E: meta-data (line=59)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="flutterEmbedding" (Raw: "flutterEmbedding")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0x2
[  +10 ms] Stopping app 'app.apk' on vivo 1811.
[   +2 ms] executing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s bea90680 shell am force-stop com.example.app
[ +335 ms] executing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s bea90680 shell pm list packages com.example.app
[+1506 ms] Installing APK.
[   +4 ms] Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
[   +3 ms] executing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s bea90680 install -t -r
C:\Users\User\Desktop\app\app\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk
[+13628 ms] Performing Streamed Install
                     Success
[   +2 ms] Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk... (completed in 13.6s)
[   +6 ms] executing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s bea90680 shell echo -n bac81bf75121878c75dc3b746ddc5ad7fecd0212 >
/data/local/tmp/sky.com.example.app.sha1
[ +216 ms] executing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s bea90680 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[ +326 ms] --------- beginning of main
                    04-06 20:01:36.264 W/GCM     ( 2998): Unexpected forwarded intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.example.app
                    flg=0x4000010 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.chimera.PersistentIntentOperationService (has extras) }
[  +12 ms] executing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s bea90680 shell am start -a android.intent.action.RUN -f 0x20000000 --ez
enable-background-compilation true --ez enable-dart-profiling true --ez enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true
com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity
[ +232 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN flg=0x20000000 cmp=com.example.app/.MainActivity (has extras) }
[   +2 ms] Waiting for observatory port to be available...
[  +14 ms] Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly
[   +5 ms] Error launching application on vivo 1811.
[   +4 ms] "flutter run" took 139,770ms.
[  +37 ms]
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:644:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1157:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1009:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:278:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:234:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #12     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #14     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #15     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:73:10)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #16     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>


[ +259 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 252ms
[   +3 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[   +3 ms] Shutdown hook priority 4
[   +7 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +1 ms] exiting with code 1
```

This method work on my phone `install APK` `open APK automatically`  and `app run` without any halt.(Because after run it break connection with my mobile that's why it run)
But when i open the same app with `android studio` it did not work.It `build apk` install it on my phone than app halt but when I remove usb cable and open the app it opens and works but after removing usb cable and after re-open the app.Hope anyone help me to resolve this issue

when I run `flutter run` on terminal it show me this

```sh
PS C:\Users\User\desktop\app\app> flutter run                                                                           Launching lib\main.dart on vivo 1811 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       119.7s
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...                11.7s
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly
Error launching application on vivo 1811.
PS C:\Users\User\desktop\app\app>_
```

Answer (score 1):

try to update your vivo device. it's working me after latest update on vivo v20pro.(version PD2020F_EX_A_6.71.2)

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal in **project/android/**, then execute `gradlew uninstallAll`, this works for me all the time.